# C# download file from PHP Web Page

Tags: c#, php, webrequest

On a server I have a php file to serve files on request, it work correctly from web browser and required file is downloaded.
Now I need to download the file from a c# application using WebRequest but it save just an empty file.

This is the php server side:

```
<?php
$file = basename($_POST['File']);
$file = '../Uploads/' . $file;

if(!file_exists($file)){ // file does not exist
    die('file not found');
} else {
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    // read the file from disk
    readfile($file);
}
?>
```

In C# application I use this code:

```
    public void DownloadFileAsync(string file)
    {
        ct = new CancellationTokenSource();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(serverURL);
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                byte[] buffer;
                buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("File=" + file);

                request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
                Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                //get response
                using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(Path.Combine(sharedFolder, values["File"])))
                    {
                        responseStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                    }
                }                }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //
            }
        }, ct.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you copying it to a `MemoryStream` and then copying it to a `FileStream` from there? The issue is that once you've written to the `MemoryStream`, the position is at the very end of the stream. There's nothing beyond it, and all the file data is behind it. Just copy from the response straight to the file. Oh and, I trust you understand that the way you're doing this means it's "fire and forget" and you might not get the file or get a complete file if your application closes before it completes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just forgot to remove this CopyTo(stream) when I copy/past the code, sorry. But I removed that line and replaced responseStream.CopyTo(fileStream); but it still create an empty file

Comment: Is your application terminating before the task completes?

Comment: @Llama No, the task is correctly completed

Comment: Step 1) Remove the `try/catch`. By the way, unless you genuinely don't care about even knowing if something failed or not, don't ever have an empty `catch`. It becomes a black hole for both expected and unexpected errors. Step 2) Set a breakpoint at `Stream requestStream = ` and step through the code line-by-line using the debugger.

Comment: @Llama In real code catch contain some code to handle errors, but no errors happens. When I debug I can't get the lenght of responseStream. responseStream.Length
'responseStream.Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146233067
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "Questo flusso non supporta operazioni di ricerca."
    Source: "System"
    StackTrace: "   at System.Net.ConnectStream.get_Length()"
    TargetSite: {Int64 get_Length()}

Comment: That's OK - it just means that the server didn't provide a length.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine, I just found out I pass the wrong url in serverURL

Comment: You should delete the question if this is the reason.